# Efficient way to get from MJPG packets to a jpeg-File in Java

Tags: image, udp, mjpeg

A professional videocamera is sending me packets over UDP and RTP, which contain MJPG-data in YUV422-pixelformat (RFC 2435). By using the DatagramSocket and DatagramPacket classes I am able to receive the packet. Now I am looking for an efficient way to get from:

approx 80 * RTP_socket.receive(rtpPacket) ---> 1 jpg-File on my Harddisk (with 25 fps)

Otherwise I am pretty soon loosing relatively many packets as, according to the UDP standard the packets are send continuously by the camera (Loosing a package once a while is not the worst as I don't need every frame).

Right now I am using a ByteBuffer to store the packets sequentially (with the header cut off using put (.. int offset...) until I got the final packet of one frame.

But unfortunately, it seems like I need to use the ImageIO.write function in order to get the necessary jpg-Header, correct? Because it cannot handle a ByteBuffer directly...

If I would do some after-processing of the image in another thread (not implemented yet), would a DirectByteBuffer make sense?

Hope you understood what I am asking :) . If not please don't hesitate to ask

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can port this C# Implementation which achieves over 100 FPS quite easily :)

https://net7mma.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Rtp/RFC2435Frame.cs

I am the author and if you need porting help let me know!